# Looking for a book about two kids who find a Roman (I think) coin and gain superpowers

Tags: story-identification, books, powers, telepathy

It's been years since I read it - a brother and sister find a an old coin and then develop powers, the centre of which is their ability to communicate with each other telepathically. When they are communicating they have increased strength and (I think) speed. Cannot for the life of me remember what it's called!

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Do you remember when you read this?

Comment: 'fraid not, possibly about 2012/13?